# Ruby HTTPI gem for Amazon Product API returns SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, httparty, amazon-product-api, httpi

I've been debugging ASIN gem for Amazon product API which uses HTTPI.get(url)
It was working fine until most recently, the HTTPI.get(url) request returns the following error:

```
HTTPI GET request to webservices.amazon.com (excon)
got response='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemSearchErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/"><Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message></Error>
<RequestId>b73cc1c9-a682-453f-a8c8-1fcc5d1f3767</RequestId></ItemSearchErrorResponse>'
```

My httpi gem is v2.2.4
I also tried using HTTParty.get(url) which works fine

What could've caused this?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a HTTPI versioning problem.

HTTPI 2.0.0 works properly, but latest version 2.2.4 has this issue